# Mongoose ensure the same row doesn't occur again

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very simple mongoose schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const followSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    follower: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    followed: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }  
});

followSchema.set('timestamps', true);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Follow', followSchema);
```

This schema holds data of users that follow other users

I Want to ensure that the same row doesn't occur again. for Example:

```
[
  {user1, user2}, // this field is valid
  {user2, user1}, // this field 
  {user1, user2}, // this field is a duplicate of field 1


]
```

I can filter before I insert the new record but I want to know if there is a cleaner or a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a unique compound index to achieve this goal

```
followSchema.index({follower:1, followed:1}, {unique:true})
```

You can read more about unique indexes on [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)